# How can i use Nagios to check linux command

Tags: ubuntu

i need to let Nagios monitor my services by checking this command:
grep -c -R 'string' /specific path

how can i add this command to nagios configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write some script (plugin) that will give exit status 0 in case of 'OK' and exit status '2' in case of problem

Please be more specific what exactly you want to check..

Please take a look on this page:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-nagios-plugins-with-bash-on-ubuntu-12-10

Comment: is there any check_command that allow me to check a linux command, like check_mysql command for example,that used to execute SQL query

Comment: Nagios RUNS linux command and check the exit status.

Make this steps and you will understand
1. touch somefile.txt
2. ls -l | grep somefile.txt
3. echo $? 
Do you see "0" - this is exit status.

Now remove the file:
1.rm somefile.txt -y
2.ls -l | grep somefile.txt
3. echo $?

You shoul see "1"; This is exit status. Nagios RUNS LINUX commadn or script (set of linux commad) and check exit status.

Comment: You can write bash or python script and check what ever you want.